# Quartz.NET UI - SilkierQuartz

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I'm having a .net core 6.0 console app using Quartz. I'm trying to use SilkierQuartz to show the jobs. I followed the instruction present at https://github.com/maikebing/SilkierQuartz but it is not clear. I enabled ConfigureWebHostDefaults on my console app and it starts a listening on localhost:5000.However when I navigate to the url I see nothing and a 404 in the logs.

Can someone help me with how to use the SilkierQuartz package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create an asp.net core app, not your console app. The problem here is you are not having the full feldge asp.net core web app.

Comment: Wouldn't ConfigureWebHostDefaults along with adding ConfigureServices and Configure make it a full-fledged web app?

Comment: No it does not contain asp.net core packages. There are two ways either add all this stuff manually or do it with asp.net core web app template. I would prefer the with project template which has all things by default